# Object reference not set to an instance of an object using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I solved the namespace problem but I still have error message. I think the problem is with getting informations into list

```
IEnumerable<XElement> InvoiceLines = from e in Document.Root
                                        .Element(P + "InvoiceLines")
                                        .Elements(P + "InvoiceLine")
                        select new XElement("InvoiceLine",
                    new XAttribute("LineNumber", e.Element(P + "ID").Value),
                    new XAttribute("ProductName", e.Element(P + "Item").Attribute(P + "Description").Value),
                    new XAttribute("UnitPriceTaxInclusive", e.Element(P + "UnitPriceTaxInclusive").Value),
                    new XAttribute("Quantity", e.Element(P + "InvoicedQuantity").Value),
                    new XAttribute("UnitCode", e.Element(P + "InvoicedQuantity").Attribute(P + "@unitCode").Value));
```

then I try to save the document using this InvoiceLines, like this:

```
XDocument FinalDocument = new XDocument( 
            new XElement("Invoice",
            new XAttribute("BuyerName", BuyerName),
            new XAttribute("SellerName", SellerName),
            new XAttribute("IssueDate", IssueDate),
            new XAttribute("ID", InvoiceID),
            new XElement("InvoiceLines", InvoiceLines)
            ));
        FinalDocument.Save(name);
        FinalDocument.Save(Console.Out);
```

error tells me that the problem is int the line "select new XElement..." in InvoiceLines

Comment: Where is your XML? You haven't shown it to us. Any one of those `.Value` property accesses could produce a NullReferenceException. I suggest removing all of those `new XAttribute` lines in your first code snippet and adding them back one at a time until you find the one that produces an error. Ideally, you should add checks to handle the situation where `e.Element()` returns an empty collection.

Comment: Are you sure the element name P + "InvoiceLines" is a valid element in your xml?

Comment: Yuval: Yes, I have specific Namespace in my P from the root element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code has a lot of assumptions about the underlying data.  For example, this:

```
e.Element(P + "Item").Attribute(P + "Description").Value
```

That segment of code assumes that:

1. `e` is guaranteed to contain an element matching `P + "Item"`
2. That element is guaranteed to contain an attribute matching `P + "Description"`

These assumptions are throughout that line.  So if data is ever encountered which doesn't meet these assumptions, `.Element()` or `.Attribute()` might return `null`, in which case the next `.` (such as in `.Value`) would be trying to dereference a `null` value, resulting in that error.

To add some null value checking, you can either separate it into multiple lines of code or put it all in-line.  The readability and maintainability of either approach is up to you.  For example, with this segment:

```
new XAttribute("LineNumber", e.Element(P + "ID").Value)
```

You might add some error checking like this:

```
new XAttribute("LineNumber", 
    (e == null ? string.Empty : 
        (e.Element(P + "ID") == null ? string.Empty :
            e.Element(P + "ID").Value)))
```

I could see where that could be pretty unreadable.  You can perhaps eliminate the first check, assuming that `e` itself will never be `null`.  But your other segments are still going to have a handful of nested checks.

To break it apart, you'd have to loop over the values instead of using a single LINQ statement.  A structure like this:

```
var InvoiceLines = new List<XElement>();
foreach (var e in Document.Root.Element(P + "InvoiceLines").Elements(P + "InvoiceLine"))
{
    // build an XElement object from e and add it to the list
}
```

This isn't *100%* identical, since it eager-loads the entire set.  So you might also separate the loop itself into another method which returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` and use `yield return` to not have to eager-load the whole thing.  It's up to you.

Come to think of it, your initial selector of data also makes assumptions:

```
Document.Root.Element(P + "InvoiceLines").Elements(P + "InvoiceLine")
```

You might want to add `null` checking there as well, just in case you ever receive data which doesn't match those predicates.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `.Value`, which can cause a `NullReferenceException` if no matching elements or attributes are found, I recommend a `(string)` cast, which will simply produce `null` if no valid value is found, and the null-coalescing operator `??`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> InvoiceLines = 
        from e in Document.Root
                          .Element(P + "InvoiceLines")
                          .Elements(P + "InvoiceLine")
        select new XElement("InvoiceLine",
                 new XAttribute("LineNumber", (string)e.Element(P + "ID") ?? ""),
                 new XAttribute("ProductName", (e.Element(P + "Item") != null) ? (string)e.Element(P + "Item").Attribute(P + "Description") ?? "" : ""),
                 new XAttribute("UnitPriceTaxInclusive", (string)e.Element(P + "UnitPriceTaxInclusive") ?? ""),
                 new XAttribute("Quantity", (string)e.Element(P + "InvoicedQuantity") ?? ""),
                 new XAttribute("UnitCode", (string)e.Element(P + "InvoicedQuantity").Attribute(P + "@unitCode") ?? ""));
```

Comment: Now it tells me that: Value cannot be null.

Comment: I've made a few updates to my answer in the past few minutes. Could you try my newest code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably some of your elements or attributes do not exist in the document. For example:

```
e.Element(P + "ID").Value
```

If there is no element `P + "ID"` the line above will throw a `NullReferenceException` as you are accessing the `Value` property of a `null` reference. You may need to do something like

```
e.Element(P + "ID") ?? 0
```

where 0 is the default value you want it to have. Or you can do this with a good old fashioned `for` loop and some `if` loops.